# get vue-select value not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-select

I am trying to get the selected value from vue-select but have used all methods and searched for help but can this to work, I also having the alert triggered when the page loads

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [      
      {id: 1, label: 'foo'},
      {id: 3, label: 'bar'},
      {id: 2, label: 'baz'},
    ],
    selected: '',
  },
  methods: {
    runme: function() {
      alert(this.selected);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2c3e5099;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#app {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.4.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Using v-model</h1>
  <v-select v-model="selected" :on-change="runme" :options="options"></v-select>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vue-select` author here. The `on-change` callback will be deprecated in `v2.5.0` and removed in `v2.6.0`. Here's the prop from the `v2.4.0` source:

```
/**
 * An optional callback function that is called  
 * each time the selected value(s) change.
 *
 * @type {Function}
 * @param {Object || String} val
 */
onChange: {
  type: Function,
  default: function (val) {
    this.$emit('input', val)
  }
}
```

As Bob Dust explained, the key here is that `onChange` calls `this.$emit('input',val)`, which is what Vue hooks into to provide the `v-model` syntax. If the event is not emitted, Vue is unaware of the change.

If you need `v-model` and also want to take an action anytime the value changes, listening for the `@input` event is the best option:

```
<v-select v-model="selected" @input="runme" :options="options"></v-select>
```

Answer (score 3):

It was your handler on `change` event that suppresses the emitting of `input` event (which actually plays in the 2 ways binding of `v-model`). You just need to listen to `input` instead:

```
<v-select v-model="selected" @input="runme" :options="options"></v-select>
```

Comment: No it's working fine without `@input`. [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/96jkar0p/1/)

Comment: of course, `@input` is unnecessary, it is for testing `alert(this.selected);` :D but overriding `change` surely breaks `v-model` behavior ;)

Answer (score 1):

Couple things here, first issue is with the `runme` method. By using `function` you are changing the context of `this`. To access the data property you should be using es6 arrow syntax:

```
  methods: {
    runme: () => {
      alert(this.selected);
    }
  }
```

Second, you really don't even need `selected` though, instead just pass the value as a parameter to `runme`.

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96jkar0p/1/).

**Updated your snippet**

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      options: [{
        value: 1,
        label: 'foo'
      }, {
        value: 3,
        label: 'bar'
      }, {
        value: 2,
        label: 'baz'
      }, ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    runme: selected => {
      alert(`label: ${selected.label} value: ${selected.value}`);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.4.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Using v-model</h1>
  <v-select :on-change="runme" :options="options"></v-select>
</div>
```